# VanillaJS issue with esc key closing popup

Tags: javascript

So if you go here
https://quantumjs.github.io/solar-popup/demo/dist/
and click on the first button and then close the popup it is fine
if you click on the button a second time and then close the popup, you get an error in the console:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null

The source can be debugged in the browser, the offending line is SolarPopup.ts:122 or can be seen in github https://github.com/quantumjs/solar-popup/blob/master/src/SolarPopup.ts#L122

This only happens if you press the ESC key, pressing the x no problem:

Issue can't be replicated if you pause the destroy method with the debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;RD**

The code is invoking the `destroyBoundWithThis` method for the current and all the old instances of `SolarPopup`

> Note: using <kbd>ESC</kbd> the first time works as expected and doesn't throw any error

This error happens because the functions (yep, a new one for every `SolarPopup` instance) registered to handle the `"keyup"` event are calling `destroyBoundWithThis` for old references to already "destroyed" instances of `SolarPopup` that are not really gone but just detached from the DOM (so they don't have a `parentElement` anymore).

```
document.addEventListener(
  "keyup", // <=== registers a new handler for every instance
  function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === KeyCodes.ESC) {
      this.destroyBoundWithThis()
    }
  }.bind(this) // <=== this could point to "destroyed" instances
)
```

https://github.com/quantumjs/solar-popup/blob/master/src/SolarPopup.ts#L85-L92

---

You could fix this by unregistering the `"keyup"` handler when you "destroy" a `SolarPopup` instance

Comment: Thanks, I thought it could be something like that, to much frameworks makes us forget about vanilla. I did think that the old instance would have been garbage collected since it wasn't part of the DOM, but oviously it was still not collected at the time. That explains why there wasn't ever more than two errrors at once, it it didn't happen when debugging with breakpoint before the remove.